# Where is the .ico file located in Windows 10 (1709) for each UWP App?

Tags: uwp, registry, windows-10-desktop, ico

I am modifying a context menu (HKCR\DesktopBackground\Shell) to add a command line to launch a UWP App.

The Added Registry Key (including the "Command" SubKey with the following string value: explorer.exe shell:AppsFolder\Full AppID) works successfully, however I wanted to Add a new string value for "Icon" but have been unable to identify where this is located.

NB. Using Run (Win+R) with the command line "shell:AppsFolder" displays each of the Apps in a Desktop Folder (from which a Desktop Shortcut with it's associated .ico file can be created) however there is no way I have found to identify the location of the source folder/files from the shortcut (they are greyed out) and thus where the icon file is stored.

The following poster <[Get file icon for shortcut from UWP Win 10 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135247/get-file-icon-for-shortcut-from-uwp-win10-application)> appears to have posed a similar question but as yet has not received any replies :( :(

Can anybody suggest where it might be found??

Comment: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ xxxxxx or also check x86 program files, but your qurstion is not on any programming as per stackoverflow guideline

Comment: Thanks Shubham ......apologies if I have asked a question outside of the guidelines....have previously found Stackoverflow a valuable source for information on registry issues but couldn't find the answer on this one :( .............unfortunately your suggested locations did not reveal any .ico files or other file sources from which to extract the icons.....so remains unresolved.....

Comment: Okay okay don't apologize to me, its stackoverflow who makes this rule , i have no difficulty to answer, let me check and provide you that location

Answer (score 0):

UWP apps do not have any *.ico file set as icon.
To set an icon for UWP app you need to enter Package.Appmanifest, go to Visual Assets tab and then find a place called "App Icon" where you can put your *.png or *.jpg files with different sizes. 
The images you add this way, will be copied to Assets folder (with properly changed name) and will be used from there.

Make a build and take a look what is stored inside *.appx files - there is folder named Assets and your images are stored and served from there (depending on what and which size is requested).

After package installation system keeps it all in c:\Program Files\WindowsApps[proper folder of your package]\Assets

Comment: RTDev....Thanks for that pointer....I had wondered whether the .png images in the Assets folder were significant....In that case, does the created shortcut (as per my ref to using Run (Win+R) with the command line "shell:AppsFolder" to display the Apps in a Desktop Folder seemingly with icons displayed & from which a Desktop Shortcut - with associated 'icon' - is created) simply display .png images rather than the traditional windows desktop .ico then?

Comment: On a related point.....if so what registry key and value would be required to display the .png image in a context menu shortcut?  .....String Value of 'Icon' with the .ico (or .exe containing icon) file path as the value data does not work using the .png file path instead.....Clearly bespoke .ico files could be created from the .png images....just wondering if there is another way?